# Hollow Square in Grid

Tags: c++, arrays, draw

So I have been trying to draw a hollow square inside of a grid. I made the grid originally with characters of "`*`" using a 2d array with width 10 and height 5. When changing each array value from specific coordinates given I draw the square from the coordinates being the upper left corner of the square. The problem is when I printed it comes out only half the outside done.

Am i missing a condition or too many conditions when rewriting parts of the grid array? Thank you for the help.

```
int main(){
    char grid[5][10];//initialize array that will be row and column
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            grid[i][j]= '*';
        }//for
    }//for loop to fill grid with asterisk
    cout << "GRID" << endl << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            cout << grid[i][j]  ;
        }//for
        cout << endl;
    }//for loop to print grid no shapes inside
    cout << endl << endl;

    int x = 2;
    int y = 3;
    int size = 3;
    char c = 'o';
    //will have a condition here to check if it can fit inside the
    //grid but this is just to test it will be a member function.
    for(int n=x-1;n<x+size-1; n++){
        for(int p=y-1;p<y+size-1; p++){
            if (n == x-1 || n==x+size-1 || p == y-1 || p== y+size-1 ){
                grid[n][p] = c;
            }
            else
                grid[n][p] = '*';
        }//for
    }//for loop to rewrite specific array coordinates with new c
    cout << "Shape inside grid." << endl;
    for(int n=0;n<5;n++){
        for(int p=0;p<10;p++){
            cout << grid[n][p];
        }//for
        cout << endl;
    }//for loop to print new grid
    return 0;
}
/*
This is my output:
**********
**ooo*****
**o*******
**o*******
**********

This is what I need:
**********
**ooo*****
**o*o*****
**ooo*****
**********
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the double `for` where you set to `'o'` the border of the square.

```
for(int n=x-1;n<x+size-1; n++){
   for(int p=y-1;p<y+size-1; p++){
      if (n == x-1 || n==x+size-1 || p == y-1 || p== y+size-1 ){
         grid[n][p] = c;
      }
      else
         grid[n][p] = '*';
   }
}
```

Your intention, if I understand well, is iterate trough the points of the square (`for(int n=x-1;n<x+size-1; n++)` and `for(int p=y-1;p<y+size-1; p++)`), check if the point is a border point (`if (n == x-1 || n==x+size-1 || p == y-1 || p== y+size-1 )`) and (a) in borders case, set `c` (that is `'o'`), (b) otherwise set `'*'`.

Good.

But you fail because the range for `n` and `p` are from `x-1` and `y-1`, included, to `x+size-1` and `y+size-1`, **excluded**.

So `n` can't be `x+size-1`: the upper (included) limit is `x+size-2`. And `p` can't be `y+size-1`: the upper (included) limit is `y+size-2`.

Concluding: your test should be

```
     if (n == x-1 || n==x+size-2 || p == y-1 || p== y+size-2 )
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Sorry,I had the right idea I guess I just miscounted. Thank you so much for your help.